# Is there a way to save a child JPA entity without the parent being present?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, orm

I have two entities which are related in a parent child manner, via a @OneToMany bidirectional relationship in spring data JPA.

The underlying tables are populated via an external feed, and there are occasions when we receive the child before the parent. The primary/foreign keys are used from the incoming feed so we know what they will be ahead of time (although we have no enforced fk constraints on the db). The data will eventually be consistent.

Is there a way to insert a child entity with a reference to the parent key, even though the parent does not yet exist.

We are using the latest version of Spring data jpa with hibernate as our provider.

Comment: Why don't you create a separate table for these "parent-less chidren... that way you can receive the child before the parent. When the parent comes check the temp table for existing children of the parent and write them to the "main" table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to insert a child entity with a reference to the parent key, even though the parent does not yet exist.

Well, one way to do it would be to add a [native SQL query](https://thorben-janssen.com/native-queries-with-spring-data-jpa/) to your `ChildEntityRepository`, something like (`.persistWhenParentNotAvailable()`).

When you know that the parent data is not available at a given point in this, you use this method to save the data.

I think you can also try to manually give to the child a parent object with only the ID field set and make sure to `NOT` have cascading configured for this `child->parent` relationship.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have a unidirectional @OneToMany. This would force JPA to use a JOIN table for managing the relationship between parent and child rather than a FK in the child table. There is an obvious overhead to this, but if performance isn't key then it may be viable.

This would allow you to persist the child free of any parent and add the parent later.

```
Child child = new Child(1);
entityManager.persist(child);

::

Parent parent = new Parent(1);
parent.addChild(child);
entityManager.persist(parent);
```